# Основная форма

Tags: delphi

Как сделать так, чтобы при закрытии главной формы (например, `form1`), программа работала (функционировала), т.е. были открыты `form2, form3...`, а не закрывались вместе с главной формой?

Answer (score 4):

Повесьте обработчик на `OnClose` с кодом:

```
procedure TForm1.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Action := caHide; // Теперь главная форма скроется вместо уничтожения caFree
end;
```

Comment: Сойдет, но лучше было бы объяснить, что главную форму нельзя закрывать, но можно скрыть. Плюс добавить что, в любом случае будут небольшие "глюки" с поведением форм (сворачивание).

Comment: Вы абсолютно правы! Но, вопрос задан - ответ получен. Здесь и сейчас он поставленную задачу решает. И, откровенно говоря, я не могу похвастаться таким огромным количеством свободного времени, чтобы превращать каждый ответ на простые по сути вопросы в развернутые мануалы "По программированию в среде Delphi". Если у Вас это время есть, напишите свой вариант ответа, люди будут благодарны. И, кстати, "глюки" на самом деле не глюки, а стандартное поведение форм связанное с архитектурой объекта Application в VCL. Просто, об этом нужно знать и учитывать в разработках. Но это к вопросу не относится.

Answer (score 0):

А можно и так:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose:=false;
  form1.Hide;
  form2.Show;
end;
```

И не будет эффекта сворачивания.
И дальше "прикручивайте" чего нужно.

Comment: Вы не по назначению используете событие `OnCloseQuery`. Оно существует для того, чтобы программист мог своим обработчиком определить можно ли в данный момент закрыть форму или нельзя (возможно спросив об этом у пользователя через MessageBox). А для того чтобы переопределить стандартное поведение VCL-формы при закрытии нужно использовать именно `OnClose`.

Comment: Замечание принял к сведению.